# Route to replace containing content when rendered

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm and old coder who's new to React/Typescript.  I've put a few pages together, but come across a conceptually simple challenge that I am struggling to solve in an elegant manner.  I hope someone can point me in the direction of an established pattern that I have not been able to find.

I have Page A that contains a Route for PageB.

When rendered, I would like Page B to replace the content of PageA rather than just being rendeerd within it.

I'm using react-dom-router 5.x

I can make this happen by declaring the PageB Route at the top of my app with all the other Routes, but a) including all an apps routes in a single file seems like an anti-pattern and b) my route would no longer be nested.

I have also tried invoking ReactDOM.render from PageB to wipe out the PageA's content.  That works fine until I hit the browser's back button and a blanked out pageA gets displayed.

This can't be an unusual requirement, so I am hoping there is an elegant way to do this, though my searches have been fruitless.

pageA  contains a link to pageB

```
export const PageA = () => {
    const {url, path} = useRouteMatch();
    return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <h3>
                    Where would you like to go today?
                </h3>
            </header>
            <nav>
                <p>
                    <Link to={`${url}/pageB`}>
                        Page B
                    </Link>
                </p>
            </nav>
            <div>
                <Route path={`${path}/pageB`}   exact>
                    <PageB/>
                </Route>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

PageB contains just a bit of text

```
export const  PageB = ()=> {
        return (
            <div>
                <main>
                    Welcome to Page B
                </main>
            </div>
        );
}
```

EDIT======================================================================
I have a solution where I extract PageA's `<header><nav>` into a variable which is conditionally rendered depending on the value of the `path` returned by `useRouteMatch()`.  It works, but not sure if it's elegant.

```
export const PageA = () => {
  const { url, path, isExact } = useRouteMatch();
  const nav =
    path === "/pageA" && isExact ? (
      <header>
          <h3>
              Where would you like to go today?
          </h3>
      </header>
      <nav>
          <p>
              <Link to={`${url}/pageB`}>
                  Page B
              </Link>
          </p>
      </nav>
      ):(
       ""
      );
   return (
      <>
        {nav}
        <Route path={`${path}/pageB`} exact>
            <PageB/>
        </Route>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I've never used 'useRouteMatch', so not sure how that works.  This is how I structured my routes in my top level component.  And then my `Header` component contains my navbar and the `Header` gets rendered on every page.  https://www.codepile.net/pile/aBpV6gNz

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I have a similar thing at the top of my app, and it pretty much works except for this scenario.  Page B just gets rendered inside Page A's inner-div, as is the expected behaviour.  I just want to make Page B replace Page A when it is rendered.  I could move the Route from Page A to the top of my app, and that would work.  I'd just lose the nested features, and have all my Routes accumulating in a single file which doesn't sound write.

Comment: So you have more routes than just A and B, but higher up in your component tree?

Comment: Yes, I originally included all the detail, but the post became too long.  This app was created using create-react-app, so has the standard index.tsx that includes the <App> component.  The top-level Routes are all defined in <App>.  the PageB Route is nested within one of those Routes, hence the use of useMatch().

Comment: If it were me, I would just swap the two components using a bool state variable instead of using routes.  And add an onClick to change that bool state.

Comment: In your render you would have something like `{showPageA ? <PageA /> : <PageB />}`

Comment: I came up with something similar just as you were suggesting that (see edit).  Maybe I'll stick with that.

Comment: Nice.  I would make your `nav` a seperate component starting with `<header>` ending with `</nav>` and then conditionally show it in your render like this: `{path === "/pageA" && isExact && <Nav />}`